# Can't expose AWS EKS to Internet using service LoadBalancer type

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, microservices, amazon-eks

I successfully created my deployment and could test it using `kubectl port-forward`, but im having a bad time exposing it to the internet.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: eks-nest-mktlab-linux-deployment
  namespace: eks-nest-mktlab
  labels:
    app: eks-nest-mktlab-linux
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: eks-nest-mktlab-linux
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: eks-nest-mktlab-linux
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: nest-mktlab-federation
          image: 538876175117.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image-1:latest
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /status
              port: 3000
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000

        - name: nest-units-service
          image: 538876175117.dkr.ecr.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/my-image-2:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3001
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: eks-nest-mktlab-loadbalancer-service
  namespace: eks-nest-mktlab
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: external
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internet-facing
  labels:
    app: eks-nest-mktlab-linux
spec:
  # if your cluster supports it, uncomment the following to automatically create
  # an external load-balanced IP for the frontend service.
  # type: LoadBalancer
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
    - port: 3000
  selector:
    app: eks-nest-mktlab-linux
```

Is there an easy way to expose my app?

Also i pretend to add 14 containers to my deployment, is it going to work or there is some limit?

First time i ran the service. The load balancer got provisioned quickly but had no instances to run, i tried to create an instance and attached to the classic load balancer that were automatically generate by kubernetes but did not work.

Then i deleted my service using kubectl and created another one with a different name and its stuck "EnsuringLoadBalancer" according to aws.

I checked my subnet and it has the 0.0.0.0 route, also security group is well configured.